# SP_HELP output to PHP array

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to create a simple PHP page that describes the tables of my DB so I can always find a table/column name or data type that I am looking for (a sort of poor man's schema if you will).

I have done this in the past with a Sybase DB but our new DB will be SQL Server so I am trying to reproduce it using that DB.

```
try {
  $conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Native Client};Server=servername,1433;Database=dbname;Uid=user;Pwd=password;");
  $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

try {
  $query = $conn->query("execute sp_help tablename");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
}
while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  print_r($result);
}
```

But it's as if I only get the first result (it doesn't loop).  I was expecting something like the example given here [SQL Server FAQ](http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server/sp_help_Getting_a_List_of_Columns_in_a_View.html) but all I get is the first row (name, owner, type, date_created) the result set does not go on to give the column names etc (which is what I'm really after).

Any ideas?

Update: According to [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx) if the argument given is a user table, it should return the columns, but in this case it does not.  All I get is...

```
Array ( [Name] => TableName [Owner] => dbo [Type] => user table [Created_datetime] => 2013-07-15 23:26:43.377 )
```

Comment: So what does sp_help do?  What result set are you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting what is given in the link I gave.  What I'm really after is the second part of that result with the column names and data types etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is create procedure on the sybase side that could call sp_help and would return require data. That procedure could be used as you need.

Answer (score 0):

The question was 10 Jears ago, but I found no other answers since. So my Solution: this works for me (not only when fetching sp_help 'tablename'):

```
private function sqlQueryMultipleRecordsets($query) {
    //echo $query;
    $stmt = $this->conn->query($query);
    if (!$stmt) {
        die("DB-Error");
    }
    $resultNr = 0;
    $result_sets = [];
    do {
        if ($stmt->columnCount() > 0) { 
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $result_sets['RS_'.(string)$resultNr][] = $row;
            }
        }
        $resultNr += 1;
    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());

    return $result_sets;
}
```